# Why google cloud function runs more that 2 minutes?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I have a function, sometimes execution (even not after "cold start") takes 2 minutes.
The local copy of the same function works in milliseconds.

Am I missing smth in google cloud configuration?

[latency stats from GCP dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Inhu.png)

Comment: This is probably not a google cloud configuration issue. This is likely to be more code related, it depends on what your code does and the amount of dependencies you are using. What have you tried? Or what do you have? Check out the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) for Google Cloud Run to help you reduce execution times.

Comment: Hi @DiegoJ, thanks for sharing this article.

Yeah, I thought that this is probably my code, but I've deployed the same code as 
Heroku app and a function (just new region at Google Cloud). 
Both options work 10 times faster.

I will check best practices, maybe I will find smth useful for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Cloud Functions you have [CPU Ghz compute power according to the memory that you allow to your Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time).

*Note: in this table, with 4Gb, you have 2vCPU @2.4Ghz, not 1vCPU at 4.8Ghz*.

By default the memory is set to 256Mb. Try to deploy with 2Gb and you will increase your performances.

*Note2: Your workstation has often 4, 8 or 16CPU @3+Ghz. Here it's only 1 @2.4Ghz max!*