# Why Cloud Function run 2min vs. 2s in local environment?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions

Quite new to GCP and not an expert of Python, I tried to run a script (reading / writing in a database with some condition) within a cloud function but it took 2min to run in GCP (even at 2gb) vs. 2s in my Jupyter notebook in local environment.
Can someone help me on how to optimise this time ? I already tried to deploy the cloud function at 2Gb but it took the same time to run ~2min
(I also already read this post : [Why google cloud function runs more that 2 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604423/why-google-cloud-function-runs-more-that-2-minutes) as well as best practice for cloud function but not so easy to understand!)

Below the script in Cloud Function (the main function is : main_binary_alert())

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import pg8000

def load_data_from_db(sql_query):
    
    db=sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "XX",
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
    
    try:
        with db.connect() as conn:
            df=pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,con=conn)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
    return df
 
def insert_data_into_db(sql_query):
    
    db=sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "XX",
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
    
    stmt=sqlalchemy.text(sql_query)
    
    try:
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(stmt)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
    return 'ok'

def check_condition(logic_condition,_to_check,check_):
    if logic_condition==None or check_==None:
        return True
    if _to_check==None:
        return False
    if logic_condition=='superieur':
        if _to_check > check_:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if logic_condition=='superieur_ou_egal':
        if _to_check >= check_:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if logic_condition=='inferieur':
        if _to_check < check_:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if logic_condition=='inferieur_ou_egal':
        if _to_check <= check_:
            return True
        else:
            return False
 
def main_binary_alert(request):
 
    try:
        X=0
        alert_param=load_data_from_db("SELECT * FROM alert_param")
        alert_criteria_binary=[1,4,8,9,16,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    alert_param_filterA=alert_param.loc[(alert_param['alert_criteria_id'].isin(alert_criteria_binary)) & (alert_param['alert_mute']==False)]
 
        
        for row in alert_param_filterA.itertuples():
 
            alert_id=row.alert_id
            alert_location_id=row.alert_location_id
            value_type_id=row.value_type_id
            logic_condition_1=row.logic_condition_1
            _condition_1=row._condition_1
            logic_condition_2=row.logic_condition_2
            _condition_2=row._condition_2
 
            last_same_alert_in_x_day=load_data_from_db("SELECT * FROM alert_reading \
            WHERE alert_id="+str(alert_id)+"\
            AND time IN (SELECT MAX(time) FROM alert_reading WHERE alert_id="+str(alert_id)+"AND time >= date_trunc('day',now()-interval '"+str(X)+"day')) \
            AND time >= date_trunc('day',now()-interval '"+str(X)+"day')")    
 
            last_check_button=load_data_from_db("SELECT * FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                    WHERE time >= date_trunc('day',now()-interval '"+str(X)+"day') \
                    AND time IN (SELECT MAX(time) FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                        WHERE time >= date_trunc('day',now()-interval '"+str(X)+"day') \
                        AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id=10 AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")) \
                    AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id=10 AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")"
            )        
            
            if last_same_alert_in_x_day.empty==True:
 
                if last_check_button.empty==True:       
 
                    sum_from_X_days=load_data_from_db(
                    "SELECT SUM() FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                    WHERE time >= date_trunc('day',now()-interval '"+str(X)+"day')\
                    AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id="+str(value_type_id)+" \
                    AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                    )
 
                    if check_condition(logic_condition_1,sum_from_X_days.iloc[0,0],_condition_1)==True & check_condition(logic_condition_2,sum_from_X_days.iloc[0,0],_condition_2)==True:
                        insert_data_into_db(
                            "INSERT INTO alert_reading (alert_id,time,location_id) S \
                            ("+str(alert_id)+",now(),"+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                        )
                        print('case: alert triggered based on counter from X days') 
                    else:
                        print('case:no alert triggered: no past same alert, no past check, no condition met') 
    
                else:
 
                    last_check_time=last_check_button.iloc[0,1]            
 
                    sum_from_last_check=load_data_from_db(
                    "SELECT SUM() FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                    WHERE time >= "+"'"+str(last_check_time)+"'"+" \
                    AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id="+str(value_type_id)+" \
                    AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                    )
 
                    if check_condition(logic_condition_1,sum_from_last_check.iloc[0,0],_condition_1)==True & check_condition(logic_condition_2,sum_from_last_check.iloc[0,0],_condition_2)==True:
 
                        insert_data_into_db(
                            "INSERT INTO alert_reading (alert_id,time,location_id) S \
                            ("+str(alert_id)+",now(),"+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                        )
                        print('case: alert triggered based on counter from past time check') 
                    else:
                        print('case:no alert triggered: no past same alert, past check, no condition met') 
 
            else:
 
                last_alert_time=last_same_alert_in_x_day.iloc[0,2]
 
                if last_check_button.empty==True:
 
 
                    sum_from_last_alert=load_data_from_db(
                    "SELECT SUM() FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                    WHERE time >= "+"'"+str(last_alert_time)+"'"+" \
                    AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id="+str(value_type_id)+" \
                    AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                    )            
 
                    if check_condition(logic_condition_1,sum_from_last_alert.iloc[0,0],_condition_1)==True & check_condition(logic_condition_2,sum_from_last_alert.iloc[0,0],_condition_2)==True:
                        #write an alert in alert_reading
                        insert_data_into_db(
                            "INSERT INTO alert_reading (alert_id,time,location_id) S \
                            ("+str(alert_id)+",now(),"+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                        )
                        print('case: alert triggered based on counter from past time alert') 
                    else:
                        print('case:no alert triggered: past same alert, no past check, no condition met') 
 
                else:
 
                    last_check_time=last_check_button.iloc[0,1] 
 
                    max_time_alert_check=max(last_alert_time,last_check_time)
 
                    sum_from_max_time_alert_check=load_data_from_db(
                    "SELECT SUM() FROM binary_reading_client1_raw \
                    WHERE time >= "+"'"+str(max_time_alert_check)+"'"+" \
                    AND value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM value WHERE value_type_id="+str(value_type_id)+" \
                    AND location_id="+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                    )  
 
                    if check_condition(logic_condition_1,sum_from_max_time_alert_check.iloc[0,0],_condition_1)==True & check_condition(logic_condition_2,sum_from_max_time_alert_check.iloc[0,0],_condition_2)==True:
                        insert_data_into_db(
                            "INSERT INTO alert_reading (alert_id,time,location_id) S \
                            ("+str(alert_id)+",now(),"+str(alert_location_id)+")"
                        )
                        print('case: alert triggered based on counter from max time alert and check') 
                    else:
                        print('case:no alert triggered: past same alert, past check, no condition met')
        
        return ("ok", 200)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
```

Comment: Perhaps you are running many statements, and each of them [incurs twice the network latency](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-network-latency-does-make-a-big-difference/).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @LaurenzAlbe. I do not run many statement as the 2min for cloud function was when testing it in the GCP environnement so basically only this function was running and no other statement are running in parallel. Also and to add some context my postgres database is hosted in GCP Cloud SQL - it is also the case when testing the python script in Jupyter notebook with execution time of 2s while 2min in gcp cloud function

Comment: Profile the program and see where the time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are stateless, and the execution environment is often initialized from scratch, which is called a cold start, this means your cloud function will be slow whenever it doesn’t run for some amount of time.The added latency is due to Cloud Functions starting up the running environment each time.

So how can you get your response time down. All you have to do is make the cloud function run on an interval. Cronjobs are made for this kind of task. As you are already running on Google Cloud Platform, check out their scheduler. You can try executing with [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-scheduler-invoke-private-functions-oidc) reference

I created a cloud scheduler job every minute to execute the cloud functions.

```
Frequency is * * * * * (means every minute).
Time Zone is US Newyork, the same region in which the cloud function was created(us-central1)
URL would be the cloud function’s endpoint and trigger URL. 
Auth Header has to be specified as an Add OIDC token and create a service account and give the role Cloud functions Invoker permissions to this service account.  
Audience is again cloud functions endpoint trigger URL.
Maximum retry attempts is 2 or anything as per your request
Max retry duration is 0s which means unlimited.
```

By scheduling a cron job every minute I am running cloud functions so that it does not have to face cold start. If a function was executed in 10 minutes or so, each time it would start from scratch and take a longer deployment time.

With this approach, the Cloud Functions will cache this running environment. So, running periodically (every 1 minute) while the cache is "hot" does not incur the startup penalty.

Note : This might lead to unwanted costs for you as scheduling the function every minute will probably deplete your free quota.

For more reference, please check [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) link for Cloud Functions and its best practices.